# Doubts about computation of the probability to get at least 2 tails in 6 throws of a rigged coin

Tags: probability

I need someone to confirm If I solved this problem correctly and tell me how to properly write the solution or notations (most of the time when I'm doing a probability problem I feel like it's more like a notation exercise than a math exercise)

> What's the probability to get at least 2 tails after flipping a rigged coin six times if getting a head is twice as likely as getting a tail?

My attempt :

P(at least 2 tails) = P(no tail) + P(1 tail) + P(2 tails)

P(no tail) = P(6 heads) = $(\frac23)^6$

P(1 tail) = $6\cdot$P(1 tail $\textbf{and}$ 5 heads) = $6\cdot$P(1 tail)$\cdot$P(5 heads) = $6\cdot\frac13\cdot(\frac23)^5$

P(2 tail) = $\frac{6!}{2!\cdot4!}\cdot$P(2 tail $\textbf{and}$ 4 heads) = $\frac{6!}{2!\cdot4!}\cdot$P(2 tail)$\cdot$P(4 heads) = $\frac{6!}{2!\cdot4!}\cdot(\frac13)^2\cdot(\frac23)^4$

then I add them up so : P(at least 2 tails) = $\frac{496}{729}$ it's greater than a half so I have some doubts that it's wrong

any elucidation would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: you found the probability of getting at most 2 tails not at least 2 tail. Other than that the maths works out

Comment: Yes, indeed; "at least 2 tails" means "tails $\geq 2$".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The calculation as far as I see it is correct, but you calculated

P(not more than 2 tails) = P(no tail) + P(1 tail) + P(2 tails)

but you wanted

P(at least 2 tails) = 1 - (P(no tail) + P(1 tail))